# Javascript / Jquery - correct practice for linking dynamically added elements to a back-end database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page that has inputs that use HTML 5 websockets to update a back-end mysql database with user input. The inputs are added to the page dynamically, and there could be any number of inputs, each for the same field on different records of a MYSQL table. (I actually have a similar scenario all the time... is that just me? :P)

So, I had to come up with a way to maintain the same functionality, but for different records across all inputs. I came up with a working method, but it seems hackish.

the HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="button updateRecord" id="updateRecord_{RECORD ID}">Update</div>
```

Javascript: (using `body.on` to make sure the binding sticks for all instances of the dynamically added element)

```
body.on("click", ".updateRecord", function () {

  // parse out the record ID from the element ID....
  var itemID = this.id.split("_")[1];

  // example of some stuff we can do with this value now:

  // getting information from related input field:
  var value = $("#someInput_"+itemID).val();

  // use that info to send a request though a websocket:
  sendMessage(itemID, value);
});
```

My question is: Is there a cleaner / more efficient way to do this? Every time I use this method I get a feeling I'm doing it wrong and there is a better way that makes more sense.

Comment: Your code doesn't look that bad.  You could change it a bit to put the record id into a separate attribute (data_record, for instance) and then you can pull the record by `var value = $(this).attrib('data_record');`

Comment: @vbguyny oh, so then you could select related elements to gather information like this: `$(".someClass[itemID='5']").val()`. I suppose there wouldn't even need to be an ID attribute at all, in that case. That does make the code cleaner :) thanks